# PostgreSQL Money type :: how to map it to Hibernate JPA?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jboss7.x

I seem to be having problems mapping the **PostgreSQL money** type to the **java.util.Currency** type using the following JPA snippet:

```
@Basic(optional = true)                                 
@Column(name = "cafl_bubgeted_amount")
private Currency bubgetedAmount;
```

column *cafl_budgeted_amount* is of type **money** in PostgreSQL.

When the code is deployed in JBoss AS 7.1.1 I get the trace shown at the end of the post.
Has anybody handled that mapping ?

#### trace when deployed in JBoss AS 7.1.3

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.Currency.getInstance(Currency.java:303) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.Currency.getInstance(Currency.java:284) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CurrencyTypeDescriptor.wrap(CurrencyTypeDescriptor.java:66) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CurrencyTypeDescriptor.wrap(CurrencyTypeDescriptor.java:35) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:66) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:65) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:269) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:265) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:357) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2695) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1552) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1484) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1384) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:640) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:856) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2058) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3697) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:439) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:251) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:954) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:903) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:610) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:150) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1006) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:883) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2463) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2279) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2274) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1115) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:252) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at gr.neuropublic.gaia.cashflow.services.TransactionGroupService.copyTransactionGroups(TransactionGroupService.java:29) [cashflow-ejb.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: `MONEY` is really painful to work with, especially with tools designed only for generic tools. I strongly recommend switching to `NUMERIC`.

Comment: Er "tools designed to work with the lowest common denominator of feature support in SQL databases". 1st effort is kind of gibberish, sorry.

Comment: BTW, if you need to you can probably write a custom mapping. These are provider specific, so see the Hibernate docs for how to implement an appropriate converter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A java.util.Currency represents a currency, like USD or EUR, not an actual amount like 456.34 from Postgres MONEY.  The exception is because it's trying to parse the number as a currency code.

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend avoiding MONEY currently and going with NUMERIC.  There are a number of specific issues.  It doesn't perform as well for arithmetic as NUMERIC does and the currency it represents is dependent on your localization settings, which means that as soon as you need multiple currencies, bad things happen.  Worse still, two different users with different localization settings will see the same amount but a different currency specified.....

Additionally DECIMAL and NUMERIC are better supported cross-db than is MONEY (but DECIMAL is just a one-way alias for NUMERIC in PostgreSQL) so going lowest common denominator suggests going with a more generic, losslessly base 10 floating point number rather than a specialized monetary amount that has interesting corner cases and gotchas.

Comment: We finally went with NUMERIC(15,2) in case of values and with NUMERIC(15,6) for things like rates. Using floating point numbers was not an option as we had to be precise. We didn't use MONEY and don't seem to be missing anything.

Comment: Numeric is a floating point, just a base 1000 instead of a base 2.  If you don't believe me try:  `select 3.999999::numeric(5,2)`   The major issue with base 2 floating numbers is not in the lack of precision but because base 2 floats can't be losslessly converted to base 10 floats and vice versa.  Base 1000 floats (numeric in PostgreSQL) don't have that problem which is why I recommended them.

Answer (score 0):

According to Cris Travers suggest, yo can change your money column to numeric type with an script like this one:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE_NAME
Alter column MY_COLUMN_NAME
type numeric(12,2);
```